# centOS 6.6 and centos 7: auto restart a service if it stopped

Tags: linux, service, centos

what is the best approach to restart a service automatically when it stopped in centos 6.6 and centos 7?

Comment: Use cron to check the status and restart. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS 7, you have to edit service file. Find the **[Service]** section in service file. And add following option:

```
Restart=on-abort
```

of like this:

```
Restart=always
```

Comment: It didn't helped out. Can you explain exactly what you want to convey.